# Why does Assert.AreEqual fail only in one direction with my custom type that has a widening conversion?

Tags: vb.net, nunit, type-conversion, equality, implicit-conversion

I'm creating a wrapped type similar to `Nullable(Of T)` and I'm writing some unit test to test equality. Like `Nullable(Of T)` I have implicit conversion between `MyWrapperType(Of T)` and `T` (both directions). Therefore, I would have expected all of the following tests in NUnit to pass:

```
Dim x = New MyWrapperType(Of DateTime)(Date.MaxValue)
Assert.True(Date.MaxValue = x)
Assert.True(x = Date.MaxValue)
Assert.True(Date.MaxValue.Equals(x))
Assert.True(x.Equals(Date.MaxValue))
Assert.AreEqual(x, Date.MaxValue)
Assert.AreEqual(Date.MaxValue, x)
```

They all do, except the last one. It tells me that:

> Failed: Expected: 9999-12-31 23:59:59.999 But was:  <12/31/9999 11:59:59 PM>

Here are some functions from my type that may be relevant. *Note:* my type has a `Value` property similiar to `Nullable(Of T)`:

```
Public Shared Widening Operator CType(value As T) As MyWrapperType(Of T)
  Return New MyWrapperType(Of T)(value)
End Operator

Public Shared Widening Operator CType(value As MyWrapperType(Of T)) As T
  Return value.Value
End Operator

Public Overrides Function Equals(other As Object) As Boolean
  If Me.Value Is Nothing Then Return other Is Nothing
  If other Is Nothing Then Return False
  Return Me.Value.Equals(other)
End Function

Public Overrides Function GetHashCode() As Integer
  If Me.Value Is Nothing Then Return 0
  Return Me.Value.GetHashCode()
End Function
```

When setting breakpoints on these methods methods for the test that fails, none of them get hit except `ToString` which gets called when they're formatting the error to display.

Why does this call to `Assert.AreEqual` only fail in one direction? Is this something wrong within `nunit.framework.dll` (using version 2.6.1.12217)? Or am I missing a bug in my code?

Comment: Shouldn't it be `Return Me.Value.Equals(other.**Value**)` in the `Equals` override?

Comment: @Bjørn-RogerKringsjå: Good point. I think an additional cast is necessary for this, as `other` is of type `object`.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

If `T` is a `Date` and you do

```
Return Me.Value.Equals(other)
```

the `other` is passed as `Object` to the `Date.Equals` method which looks like this:

```
Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal value As Object) As Boolean
    If TypeOf value Is DateTime Then
        Dim time As DateTime = CDate(value)
        Return (Me.InternalTicks = time.InternalTicks)
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

And as you can see the first condition will return `False`.

```
Dim isdate As Boolean = (TypeOf CObj(New MyWrapperType(Of Date)(Date.MaxValue)) Is Date)
```

To ensure correct casting you can do something like this:

```
Public Overrides Function Equals(other As Object) As Boolean
    If (TypeOf other Is MyWrapperType(Of T)) Then
        Dim obj As MyWrapperType(Of T) = DirectCast(other, MyWrapperType(Of T))
        '...Me.Value.Equals(obj.Value)
    ElseIf (TypeOf other Is T) Then
        Dim obj As T = DirectCast(other, T)
        '...Me.Value.Equals(obj)
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

**Edit**

If we disassemble the `Assert.AreEqual` method it looks like this:

*Call 1* : Assert

```
Public Shared Sub AreEqual(ByVal expected As Object, ByVal actual As Object)
    Assert.AreEqual(expected, actual, String.Empty, Nothing)
End Sub
```

*Call 2* : Assert

```
Public Shared Sub AreEqual(ByVal expected As Object, ByVal actual As Object, ByVal message As String, ByVal ParamArray parameters As Object())
    Assert.AreEqual(Of Object)(expected, actual, message, parameters)
End Sub
```

*Call 3* : Assert

```
Public Shared Sub AreEqual(Of T)(ByVal expected As T, ByVal actual As T, ByVal message As String, ByVal ParamArray parameters As Object())
    If Not Object.Equals(expected, actual) Then
        Dim str As String
        If (((Not actual Is Nothing) AndAlso (Not expected Is Nothing)) AndAlso Not actual.GetType.Equals(expected.GetType)) Then
            str = CStr(FrameworkMessages.AreEqualDifferentTypesFailMsg(IIf((message Is Nothing), String.Empty, Assert.ReplaceNulls(message)), Assert.ReplaceNulls(expected), expected.GetType.FullName, Assert.ReplaceNulls(actual), actual.GetType.FullName))
        Else
            str = CStr(FrameworkMessages.AreEqualFailMsg(IIf((message Is Nothing), String.Empty, Assert.ReplaceNulls(message)), Assert.ReplaceNulls(expected), Assert.ReplaceNulls(actual)))
        End If
        Assert.HandleFail("Assert.AreEqual", str, parameters)
    End If
End Sub
```

*Call 4* : Object

```
Public Shared Function Equals(ByVal objA As Object, ByVal objB As Object) As Boolean
    Return ((objA Is objB) OrElse (((Not objA Is Nothing) AndAlso (Not objB Is Nothing)) AndAlso objA.Equals(objB)))
End Function
```

**Assert.AreEqual(x, Date.MaxValue)** = True

This would end up in this:

```
New MyWrapperType(Of DateTime)(Date.MaxValue).Equals(Date.MaxValue)
```

which finally ends up calling your `Equals` method:

```
Public Overrides Function Equals(other As Object) As Boolean
    If Me.Value Is Nothing Then Return other Is Nothing <- Pass, Value is Date.MaxValue, not null
    If other Is Nothing Then Return False <- Pass, other is Date.MaxValue, not null
    Return Me.Value.Equals(other) <- Pass, Value (Date.MaxValue) = other (Date.MaxValue)
End Function
```

**Assert.AreEqual(Date.MaxValue, x)** = False

This would end up in this:

```
Date.MaxValue.Equals(New MyWrapperType(Of DateTime)(Date.MaxValue))
```

which finally ends up calling your `Date.Equals(obj As Object)` method:

```
Public Overrides Function Equals(ByVal value As Object) As Boolean
    If TypeOf value Is DateTime Then '< Fail, value is not a DateTime, it's a MyWrapperType(Of T)
        Dim time As DateTime = CDate(value)
        Return (Me.InternalTicks = time.InternalTicks)
    End If
    Return False
End Function
```

Comment: Or would it be preferable to have overloads of `Equals` so that there's no unboxing?

Comment: That doesn't solve the problem. I've edited the question to include this, but setting breakpoints on key methods in my class (type conversion and equals), none of them get hit for the test that fails (except `ToString` which gets called when they're formatting the error to display).

Comment: Presumably it is calling `Date.Equals(value As Object)` and it isn't using the implicit type conversion and therefore failing. What's odd though, it that `Date.MaxValue.Equals(x)` worked in my test, despite `x` not being a `Date` type (when I run that test, the widening function on my type does get called).

Comment: @JeffBridgman And if `Date.MaxValue.Equals(x)` worked, it may be that the compiler is casting it? I mean, x is still `MyWrapperType(Of T)` not `Object`. Just for fun, try `Date.MaxValue.Equals(CObj(x))`.

Comment: @JeffBridgman Come to think of it, by calling `Date.Equals` when `x` is still `MyWrapperType(Of T)`, it will be casted as `Date` and ends up in `Date.Equals(value As DateTime)`. While `CObj(x)` ends up in `Date.Equals(value As Object)` and fails as shown.

Comment: So does that suggest that somewhere inside `Assert.Equals` my `x As MyWrapperType(Of T)` is getting `CObj` (or something similar) called on it? Otherwise I don't see why it wouldn't just cast to `Date` and succeed as it does when I do `Date.MaxValue.Equals(x)`.

Comment: @JeffBridgman Yes, here: `AreEqual(expected As Object, actual As Object)` Did you not see my edit? Try this and you'll see you get a `True, False`: `MsgBox(String.Format("{0}, {1}", Date.MaxValue.Equals(x), Date.MaxValue.Equals(CObj(x))))`

Comment: @JeffBridgman BTW, _Step 4_ `Equals` is a method of `Object`, not `Assert`. _Step 3_: `If Not Object.Equals(expected, actual) Then`

Comment: Thanks for all your help! I kind summarized what I got out of it in another answer if you want to take a look.

Answer (score 1):

Here's the cause to best of my understanding based off of the answer by Bjørn-Roger Kringsjå:

When I call `Assert.True(Date.MaxValue.Equals(x))` the `Date.Equals(other As Date)` override gets called, as well as my widening operator on my type. It appears the compiler is choosing the most specific `Equals` override here (the one for `Date`) using my implicit type conversion.

When I call  `Assert.AreEqual(Date.MaxValue, x)`, the NUnit method calls `Object.Equal(a, b)` which then delegates it to `Date.Equals(other As Object)` method. This method returns false if `other` is not a `Date`. Therefore the assert fails.

If `Assert.AreEqual` had an override that takes dates (or maybe even two parameters of a generic type `T`?), it probably would have been fine, but since the only override that matches was for objects, my type conversions weren't able to come to save the day.

Answer (score 1):

There are two ways your structure type could be converted to satisfy some overload of `DateTime.Equals()`: the compiler can use your implicit conversion operator to yield a `DateTime`, or it can do a boxing conversion to `Object`.  There are many situations where, when multiple overloads are possible, the compiler should assume they're equivalent and just pick one without squawking.  Unfortunately, the overloads of `Equals` are not equivalent (IMHO, the methods should have different names).  The first four tests work because they choose an overload which causes the argument to be converted to the type of the thing doing the comparing.

The fifth assertion *should* fail because it's using the other overload which does not perform type coercion.  The reason it succeeds is that your `Equals` method fails to abide by the `Equals` contract.  No object of any type may legitimately report itself as equal to any object which will not reciprocate.  Since no `DateTime` will consider itself equivalent to a non-converted instance of your type, your type must not consider itself equal to a non-converted `DateTime`.

If you dislike having inconsistent behavior with `someWrapper.Equals(someDateTime)` and `someWrapper.Equals((Object)someDateTime)`, I would suggest that the best solution may be to declare overloads of `==` and `!=` for `(DateTime, WrapperType)` and `(WrapperType, DateTime)` and mark them with an `[Obsolete]` attribute.  That would cause the compiler to squawk at any effort to directly compare instances of your wrapper type to `DateTime` without first converting types so they match.